# Calling a REST API from JScript?

Tags: rest, web-services, jscript

I am working on a platform which only supports JScript. And I am very virgin to JScript. Now I need to call a REST API from JScript to get a value.

URI : https://example.com:1234/getToken/cs?action=CE&data=1234567890124

This will return a JSON or Text (Can specify with an additional parameter with the URL)

Request Type: **GET**
No authentication required.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using jQuery library :

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://example.com:1234/getToken/cs?action=CE&data=1234567890124",
   type: "GET"
   success: function(response){
     console.log(response);
   }
});
```

Comment: Can I use JQuery in JScript?